# Joomla JFactory::getDBO() - Prefix is wrong?

Tags: jdatabase, jfactory, external-script

I am pretty new to Joomla, and I'm stuck!

I'm trying to access the Joomla DB from a PHP script, using the JFactory::getDBO(); method. I noticed all my queries were returning '0' results, even though the SQL looks fine.

I then noticed that

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
echo "Database prefix is : " . $db->getPrefix();
```

Outputs:

```
"Database prefix is : jos_".
```

My DB Prefix should be - "wvfd_".

This is the part of code that initializes joomla:

```
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..' ));


    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

    $mainframe =&JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

I have checked in the Joomla backend, and the prefix is set correctly. I have checked configuration.php, and it is set correctly in there too?

Why is $db = JFactory::getDBO(); connecting me to a DB that does not exist?

All/Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of Joomla running in different directories? If so, be sure that your `JPATH_BASE` is defined correctly and pointing to the correct directory as you have have a different prefix on different installations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your db prefix, you need to create object of Jconfig class(configuration file). Let us suppose you are creating a file connectivity.php and place it root. And the code in that file would be :

```
require_once ('configuration.php' );

    $var_cls = new JConfig();
    $connlink = mysql_connect($var_cls->host, $var_cls->user, $var_cls->password) or die("Connection Failure to Database");
    mysql_select_db($var_cls->db, $connlink);

 return $db_prefix = $var_cls->dbprefix;
```

$db_prefix will give you the correct prefix of your db.

Comment: Thanks Nehal. Your post pointed me in the right direction, and combined with http://network.convergenceservices.in/forum/40-joomla-tricks/2148-connecting-to-another-database-using-jdatabase-in-joomla.html my issue is now resolved!